# Apply resampling to each group in a groupby object

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I've created a convenience method to perform resampling on an arbitrary dataframe:

```
def resample_data_to_hourly(df):
  df = df.resample('1H',how='mean',fill_method='ffill',
                           closed='left',label='left')
  return df
```

And I would like to apply this function to every dataframe in a groupby object with something like the following:

```
df.transform(resample_data_to_hourly)
df.aggregate(resample_data_to_hourly)
dfapply(resample_data_to_hourly)
```

I've tried them all with no success.
No matter what I do, no effect is had on the dataframe, even if I set the resulting value of the above to a new dataframe (which, to my understanding, I shouldn't have to do).

I'm sure there is something straightforward and idiomatic about handling groupby objects with time series data that I am missing here, but I haven't been able to correct my program.

How do I create functions like the above and have them properly apply to a groupby object?
I can get my code to work if I iterate through each group as in a dictionary and add the results to a new dictionary which I can then convert back into a groupby object, but this is terribly hacky and I feel like I'm missing out on a lot of what Pandas can do because I'm forced into these hacky methods.

EDIT ADDING BASE EXAMPLE:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='10m')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng), 'b':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)})
```

yields:

```
                       a         b
    2000-01-31  0.168622  0.539533
    2000-11-30 -0.283783  0.687311
    2001-09-30 -0.266917 -1.511838
    2002-07-31 -0.759782 -0.447325
    2003-05-31 -0.110677  0.061783
    2004-03-31  0.217771  1.785207
    2005-01-31  0.450280  1.759651
    2005-11-30  0.070834  0.184432
    2006-09-30  0.254020 -0.895782
    2007-07-31 -0.211647 -0.072757

df.groupby('a').transform(hour_resample) // should yield resampled data with both a and b columns
// instead yields only column b
// df.apply yields both columns but in this case no changes will be made to the actual matrix
// (though in this case no change would be made, sample data could be generated such that a change should be made)
// if someone could supply a reliable way to generate data that can be resampled, that would be wonderful
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you boiled it down to a small example dataset and then show the code you would use for the example that doesn't work.

Comment: i've added some example as to what the problem is.  the sample data generated isn't particularly good, but anything larger that would be appropriate to resample would be awkward to put there :-/.  if anyone has a good way of making smallish data that is appropriate for resampling, it would be wonderful if they could supply it.

Comment: There is no point grouping on 'a' in your example. They are just random numbers; none of the values repeat so each value in 'a' would be a group and the resample want do anything.

Comment: while it is unhelpful to print the sample array from it, the same results occur with the following parameters:
 rng = pd.date_range(start = '01-01-2000 10:00', end = '01-01-2000 11:00', freq='30s');;
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng), 'b':pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)});;
df.apply(hour_resample)

Comment: am i just using pandas incredibly badly?  i am used to being able to groupby and apply a transformation without difficulty.  am i supposed to do things differently for this application for some reason?

Comment: ah, no, you're right.  i applied a transformation that makes the groupby for 'a' effective, and the `transform` then works.  now i just need to figure out what is different about my actual data.

Answer (score 3):

```
data.groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda d: d.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                      .resample("M", how=""))
```