# Pandas group given divide point

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, where I need do divide into several groups and do certain aggregation within each.

I have a column which is `datetime` where I need efficiently use a given list of cutting points to split the dataframe into different groups.

In plain english, I want to find today's `(0)` data as the first window, then the past week before yesterday as the second window `(1 ~ 7)`, and so and and so forth. There isn't really a pattern in the cutting points so it is not a simple matter of using `modulo`.

The cutting points are `cutover = [1, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 180]`.

This is what i have so far but using for loop and create a new window every time isn't the most efficient way:

```
result = []
for s,e in zip(cutover[:-1], cutover[1:]):
    print s, e
    date_start = date_latest - timedelta(e)
    date_end = date_latest - timedelta(s)
    df_window = df[(df.date > date_start) & (df.date <= date_end)] 
    avgInventory = df_window.qty.mean()
    ...
    result.append(...)
```

Can anyone share with me any built-in methods that I can use to do this type of customized group?

Comment: I'd suggest trying something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485673/apply-resampling-to-each-group-in-a-groupby-object

Answer (score 0):

I fashioned this example for you:

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=4800, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(np.random.randn(4800, 2) / 100 + 0.0002) - 1, tidx, list('AB'))
```

#### Gratuitous chart

```
df.add(1).cumprod().plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

#### Solution

Take the time differences between most recent date and all other dates.  From those differences, take the day count.  Finally, create bins based on those day counts.

```
bins = [0, 1, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 180, 200]
cuts = pd.cut((df.index[-1] - df.index).days, bins)

df.groupby(cuts).agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])
```

[image]